# C error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token

Tags: c, data-structures

so I'm learning data structures and pretty much new to C. I am trying to make a function that accepts student id and the course number and the output would be the student name and course name. I'm currently stuck at the input part. Here's the code I have so far:

```
typedef struct Student Student;
typedef struct Course Course;
typedef struct Node Node;
typedef struct Node* NodePtr;

struct Student{
    int id;
    char name[30];
    double gpa;
    int ch;
};

struct Course{
    int id;
    char code[10];
    char name[30];
    int ch;
};

void displayStudents() {

     struct Student students[10]={
        {1, "ahmed" ,3.6,43},
        {2, "mohamed", 3.2, 40},
        {3,"hassan", 3.0, 41},
        {4, "hossam", 2.5, 35},
        {5, "hany", 2.3, 32},
        {6, "hala", 2.7, 37},
        {7, "hana", 2.8, 33},
        {8, "ramadan",3.8,46},
        {9, "sameh",3.7,43},
        {10, "nour",3.3,42}
     };

      for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%d,%s,%lf, %d", students[i].id, students[i].name, students[i].gpa, students[i].ch);
        printf("\n");
      }

}

void displayCourses() {

    struct Course courses[3] = {
    {30, "CS212", "DataStructure", 3},
    {40, "CS233", "Architecture", 3},
    {50, "GM300", "Multimedia", 3}

    };

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {

        printf("%d - %s - %s - %d", courses[i].id, courses[i].code, courses[i].name, courses[i].ch);
        printf("\n");
    }


}

void Registeration(struct Student student, *struct Course courses) {

          printf("Select a student: \n");
          gets(student.name);
          printf("Enter his ID: ");
          scanf("%d", &student.id);
          printf("Select a course: ");
          scanf("%d",&course.id);


}
```

I'm getting the error in the registeration function. I tried removing the pointer but it caused other problems, I've also tried lots of other stuff but to no avail.

Here's the error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Data Structure Project (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\Shiko\Desktop\C Tutorials\Data structure project\main.c|155|error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: `*struct Course courses` Guess you meant `struct Course courses` there, without the `*`. That will allow the code to compile, but it's still most likely wrong because `student` and `courses` are passed by value, so whatever you write to those structures will not be returned to or seen by the calling code. Please post the complete code, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've editted it and added the structures itself.

Comment: As pointed out `*struct Course courses` is just not valid C syntax. More likely what you need is; `void Registeration(struct Student *student, struct Course *courses)`. Then need to modify function body to use pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not valid syntax

```
void Registeration(struct Student student, *struct Course courses)
```

I suspect you either mean

```
void Registeration(struct Student student, struct Course courses)
```

or

```
void Registeration(struct Student student, struct Course *courses)
```

depending on whether you want to pass the struct as arg or a pointer to the struct.